# How to use unicode characters and greek letters together in an annotate element of a plot made with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, unicode, annotations, annotate

I want to write 1 << αβ using annotate, but I have not been successful. Could someone help me do this?

```
library(ggplot2)

# Only greek letters

ggplot() +
  annotate(geom = "text",
           label = "1*alpha*beta*t",
           parse = TRUE,
           x = 0,
           y = 0)
```

[image]

```
# Greek letters + unicode

ggplot() +
  annotate(geom = "text",
           label = "1* \U226A *alpha*beta*t",
           parse = TRUE,
           x = 0,
           y = 0)

Error in parse(text = text[[i]]) : <text>:1:4: unexpected input
1: 1* «
       ^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot() +
  annotate(geom = "text",
           label = as.character(expression(paste("1 << ",alpha, beta))),
           parse = TRUE,
           x = 0,
           y = 0)
```

[image]
Or this way

```
ggplot() +
  annotate(geom = "text",
           label = as.character(expression(paste("1","\U226A", alpha, beta))),
           parse = TRUE, size = 5,
           x = 0,
           y = 0)
```

[image]